# Display gzip in console log without using text file

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to download and then display gzip file in console log without writing content in text file.

```
 request(URL,  (err, res, body) => {
            console.log(body);
          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use streams. You can simply [pipe request to zlib](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-20-nodejs-transform-streams.html#uncompressing_stream_with_gzip) (a standard module) to decompress it. Then pipe it to `process.stdout` to have it logged into the console like this:

```js
const request = require('request');

const zlib = require('zlib');
const gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();

request('http://example.com/someFile.txt.gz').pipe(gunzip).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Note: if the file is large it's going to be logged in chunks as data gets downloaded and processed.

If you'd like to wait until all the data is downloaded log it afterward you could use [stream-to-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-to-promise):

```js
const gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
const streamToPromise = require('stream-to-promise');

const unzipStream = request('http://example.com/someFile.txt.gz').pipe(gunzip);

streamToPromise(unzipStream)
    // `data` is a buffer here, so you need to call .toString() to log it
    .then(data => console.log(data.toString()))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```